# Unable to compile maven project in jenkins while it is working fine in the eclipse "Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later"

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

i am using maven project for the automation, when i execute scripts from eclipse it is working fine when I tries to run scripts from the Jenkins then system shows me an error

[ERROR] Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.

JKD : 12 ,
windows :10 ,
Jenkins :
maven :

i am using the below maven plugins

```
    [![<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>EventBuizz</groupId>
  <artifactId>EventBuizz</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>


  </properties>
  <dependencies>



  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-tree</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Selenium -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- TestNG -->
        <dependency>                
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                               
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                             
            <version>6.14.3</version>                               
            <scope>test</scope>                                     
       </dependency>

       <!--JUnit -->

   <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <!--Maven Plugin -->
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>



</dependency>  



</dependencies>



  <build>
  <plugins>

 <!--Maven Plugin -->  
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

 <!--Maven surfire plugin -->
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
  </build>





</project>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 3):

with these lines:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
```

You are forcing compilation of your project to Java 6, no matter what version of the JDK you use.

Jenkins is telling you it doesn't support Java 6 anymore. Just update that version to a later one.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer , How i can update my java version in jenkins?

Comment: i have updated my java version in the porm.xml but still facing same issu    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

Comment: Thanks i have fixed this problem through this :  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

Answer (score 1):

The maven version in your build server does not support java 6, and you are forcing the compilation to java 6 througth your pom.xml. You have two option depending on your requirement either correct the pom.xml to a highier java version or point jinkens to an older maven version.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are SOL w/java12.

According to the Oracle Java docs,
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/javac.html

source release
Specifies the version of source code accepted. The following values for release are allowed:

Note:
Beginning with JDK 9, javac no longer supports -source release settings less than or equal to 5. If settings less than or equal to 5 are used, then the javac command behaves as if -source 6 were specified

Solution:
You can go all the way back to java 1.2 using Java 8:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Use a maven toolchain / profiles to be able to  dynamically choose which to use:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html